Tbl_regression does not work properly with BRMS output
I have fitted a multivariate ordinal regression in BRMS:
data(mtcars)
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,ordered = T)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,ordered=T)
test <- brm(mvbind(cyl,gear) ~ disp + hp + qsec + wt, family = cumulative('probit', threshold = "flexible"), data=mtcars, chains=1)
tbl_regression(test)

I am looking for a way to create a publishable output and tbl_regression is supposed to work with BRMS. However, when I attempt to use it, I get an (incorrect) table with two errors:
> tbl_regression(test)
✖ Unable to identify the list of variables.

This is usually due to an error calling stats::model.frame(x)or stats::model.matrix(x).
It could be the case if that type of model does not implement these methods.
Rarely, this error may occur if the model object was created within
a functional programming framework (e.g. using lappy(), purrr::map(), etc.).
Warning message:
In tidy.brmsfit(x, ..., effects = "fixed") :
  some parameter names contain underscores: term naming may be unreliable!

tbl_regression does not seem to be able to label/distinguish my different response variables and therefore the output looks like this:

Any idea on what to do or how to fix this? Can't seem to get it to display this output properly. Any solutions or even workarounds are highly appreciated.
